# Chatbot with Multiple QnA Maker Knowledge Base and Intents in LUIS - sdk v4 C#

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am developing a bot which currently has one KB mapped to one Intent in LUIS through dispatch tool. I followed the [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) article to create the dispatch.

I want to create more KB's in the same QnA service and map them to multiple intents through creating a dispatch file. The Microsoft article that I followed uses `Case` switch statements to determine between multiple intents. This seems very code dependent to me.

The questions is: If I create multiple intents and KB's through dispatch file is there a way I can get rid of these case switch statements? Or I have to create multiple case switch statements for every Knowledge Base so the bot maps to the correct KB?

I have the following code:

```
 private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> 
 turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, 
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        switch (intent)
        {
            case "l_HomeAutomation":
                await ProcessHomeAutomationAsync(turnContext, 
        recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, 
     cancellationToken);
                break;
            case "l_Weather":
                await ProcessWeatherAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                break;
            //case "q_sample-qna":
            case "q_CivicSampleFAQ":
                await ProcessSampleQnAAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                break;
            default:
                _logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");
              // await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}."), cancellationToken);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Basically the case `q_CivicSampleFAQ` determines that the intent processed should get the reply from QnA Maker KB. If i have multipe KB's I can create multiple cases but this would restrict me to code change every time I have a new KB or even if the name of an old KB is changed. ANy ideas how to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft offers a QnA Maker package which utilizes the Cognitive Services API, from there you can download and store a list of all KBs, their IDs, and their data.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA/

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_getknowledgebasesforuser

Beyond this, you'll have to create your own map of relation between the intents and the KBs you want to target. Once you have that done though, it'd be a simple matter of receiving an intent and dispatching to the appropriate KB based on your mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That mapping will be in code and I have that right now. My question was is there a way to not have it and make it dynamic? Like if i add a new KB and intent using dispatch, i will have to map it in the code file as well. SO every time a new KB is used i have to make a code change?

Comment: plus how would my appsetting.json would look like with multiple KBs?

Comment: Yes, what I am saying is you shouldn't make it in your code. Instead either use a database or just a file to store this information. That way you can change it on the fly.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. ty!